# Getting SQL Server database entries to update? VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am having trouble getting my SQL Server database to update. I think there's something wrong with the syntax but I'm unsure.

I tried writing it even in SQL Server itself and I still see a "syntax" error but I don't get what's wrong with the syntax! It works every other time I put basically the same code and nothing has changed! ... has it? LOL

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    'update salesperson button
    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("server=classified;database=classified")
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
    Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Home Address]=@HomeAddress AND City=@City AND State=@State AND [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber"
    Dim repeatChecker As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, myconnection)
    'mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must add a first name.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox7.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must add a last name.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox8.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must add a home address.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox9.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You must add a city.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox10.Text.Length <> 2 Then
        MsgBox("State abbreviation needed.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox11.Text = "" Or TextBox12.Text = "" Or TextBox13.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please ensure you have entered a valid telephone number: (XXX) (XXX) (XXXX).", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf Firs.IsInputNumeric(TextBox11.Text) = False Or Firs.IsInputNumeric(TextBox12.Text) = False Or Firs.IsInputNumeric(TextBox13.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please ensure you have entered a valid telephone number: (XXX) (XXX) (XXXX).", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox11.Text.Length <> 3 Or TextBox12.Text.Length <> 3 Or TextBox13.Text.Length <> 4 Then
        MsgBox("Please ensure you have entered a valid telephone number: (XXX) (XXX) (XXXX).", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox6.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox7.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@HomeAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox8.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox9.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text.ToUpper
        repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text + "-" + TextBox12.Text + "-" + TextBox13.Text
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = repeatChecker.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                ' User already exists
                MsgBox("This salesperson already exists in the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Else
                reader.Close()
                mycommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Salespeople SET [First Name]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox6.Text) + "', [Last Name]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox7.Text) + "', [Home Address]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox8.Text) + "', City='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox9.Text) + "', State='" + TextBox10.Text.ToUpper + "', [Phone Number]='" + TextBox11.Text + "-" + TextBox12.Text + "-" + TextBox13.Text + "' WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName, [Last Name]=@LastName, [Home Address]=@HomeAddress, City=@City, State=@State, [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber)", myconnection)
                mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                BindGridSalespeople()
                TabControl1.SelectTab(0)

                Dim FirstNameDisplay As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text)
                Dim LastNameDisplay As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox2.Text)
                MsgBox("Salesperson " + FirstNameDisplay + " " + LastNameDisplay + " successfully added.")
            End If
        End Using
        myconnection.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Specifically, this line near the bottom:

```
mycommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Salespeople SET [First Name]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox6.Text) + "', [Last Name]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox7.Text) + "', [Home Address]='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox8.Text) + "', City='" + Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox9.Text) + "', State='" + TextBox10.Text.ToUpper + "', [Phone Number]='" + TextBox11.Text + "-" + TextBox12.Text + "-" + TextBox13.Text + "' WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName, [Last Name]=@LastName, [Home Address]=@HomeAddress, City=@City, State=@State, [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber)", myconnection)
```

---

IS MY LOGIN FORM CORRECT AND FREE OF SQL ATTACKS BY INJECTION?

---

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("server=CLASSIFIED;database=classified")
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim loginQuery As String = " SELECT Username, Password FROM Accounts WHERE (Username = @Username) AND (Password = @Password)"
    Dim loginCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(loginQuery, myconnection)
    loginCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    loginCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text

    Using reader As SqlDataReader = loginCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            ' User already exists
            MsgBox("Logged in successfully as " & TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Firs.Show()


        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid username or password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

        End If
    End Using
        myconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you mixing string concatenation and prepared statements...?  You haven't told us what the syntax error is, but I would assume it has something to do with the values you're injecting from the textboxes.  Just use parameters for the entire query.

Comment: You should be using Prepared Statements *always* for insert/update statements instead of raw SQL concatenation... this is how you get [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: This might sound dumb but can you tell me which part of my code the prepared statement is and which one the string concatenation is?

Comment: what a messy code :3

Comment: What would you suggest then, excalibur?

Comment: @0as9d8g7as : you see how the string that you're assigning to `theQuery` is a continuous string rather than patching several strings together? In it, you define parameter names that are populated below. That's the "right" way to do this. Compare it to the way you build the string in `myCommand` (which involves string-concatenation). The first thing I'd do is replace all those plusses with ampersands. But it would help us if you'd give us proper details about what error you receive on what line.

Comment: You should look at separating your code into layers. Your code is all super tightly coupled with validation and data layers. If anything ever changes you are going to pull your hair out trying to maintain this. And seriously, you need to give reasonable names to your controls. TextBox1 is useless as a name.

Comment: The 2 comments above me are helpful. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: Would you guys say my login form is correct? I tried modifying this first as it is less complex. Check the added code in my question.

Comment: The query in your login form is correctly parameterized. Where are you on the syntax error you were getting?

Answer (score 0):

Besides structural changes recommeded by the comments, there are issues with your WHERE clause.  1: Remove the parenthesis after the PhoneNumber parameter.  2: Different Where clauses should be separated by "AND " instead of commas.

```
"' WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName, [Last Name]=@LastName, [Home Address]=@HomeAddress, City=@City, State=@State, [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber)", myconnection)
```

Becomes:

```
"' WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Home Address]=@HomeAddress AND City=@City AND State=@State AND [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber", myconnection)
```